# user defined function variables are getting overwritten somewhere

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

Hello I have a user defined function `lambda` ,  into which I am passing age (integer), gender (integer) and a file (BMI).. When I call it I get some value, which is wrong. But when I execute each statements in the function I get the right answer. Strange thing is

1. after I executing single statements from the function and getting the expected answer, if I call the function again, I get the right answer.
2. Then if change the values when calling the function, it gives the old answer (of step #1). And it never changes until I execute single statements from the function (as in the step #1)

Can someone please help me..

```
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {

        sel <- subset(ibmi, age==ag & gender == gnd)
        out <- boxcox(lm(sel$bmi~1))
        rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
        return (rn[1] + rn[2])/2
    }
```

This is how I call the function..

```
> lambda(14,1,bmi)
[1] -0.4040404
```

Executing each statements frm the fn

```
> sel <- subset(bmi, age==14 & gender == 1)
> out <- boxcox(lm(sel$bmi~1))
> rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
> (rn[1] + rn[2])/2
[1] -0.3636364
```

Again I call the function

```
> lambda(14,1,bmi)
[1] -0.3636364
```

Calling function with different value for Age

```
> lambda(17,1,bmi)
[1] -0.3636364

> dput(head(bmi[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)], 50))
structure(list(age = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), gender = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), diabetic = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "No", "Yes"
), class = "factor"), height = c(117, 117.5, 123, 133.5, 110.2, 
126, 119, 113.8, 125.8, 115.6, 124.1, 117.8, 128, 117, 121, 116.6, 
111.3, 116, 118, 123, 119.5, 118.3, 121.5, 116.4, 121, 110, 114, 
116, 113.5, 115.5, 111.7, 116.5, 121.6, 129.9, 115.3, 116, 116.5, 
122.2, 123.4, 118, 117, 107.2, 116.5, 126.6, 118.2, 119.6, 141, 
118.7, 150.6, 113), weight = c(21.2, 21, 19.2, 36.7, 18.1, 42.6, 
36.2, 18.6, 25.1, 20.1, 40.2, 29.7, 32.6, 20.4, 24.5, 20.9, 17.3, 
22, 21.4, 23.5, 27.5, 23.3, 33.4, 22.2, 24, 16.9, 18.8, 23, 20.1, 
20.8, 26.4, 21.5, 41.2, 47.1, 31.4, 18.9, 27.1, 33.6, 26.2, 21.3, 
20, 17.6, 22.7, 24.3, 19.9, 32, 45.4, 21.4, 20.9, 21.2), bmi = c(15.49, 
15.21, 12.69, 20.59, 14.9, 26.83, 25.56, 14.36, 15.86, 15.04, 
26.1, 21.4, 19.9, 14.9, 16.73, 15.37, 13.97, 16.35, 15.37, 15.53, 
19.26, 16.65, 22.63, 16.39, 16.39, 13.97, 14.47, 17.09, 15.6, 
15.59, 21.16, 15.84, 27.86, 27.91, 23.62, 14.05, 19.97, 22.5, 
17.21, 15.3, 14.61, 15.32, 16.73, 15.16, 14.24, 22.37, 22.84, 
15.19, 9.22, 16.6), systolic = c(108L, 104L, 93L, 103L, 99L, 
103L, 130L, 105L, 131L, 102L, 104L, 137L, 129L, 84L, 116L, 101L, 
108L, 101L, 92L, 111L, 100L, 112L, 107L, 118L, 112L, 104L, 108L, 
140L, 100L, 78L, 103L, 100L, 119L, 106L, 110L, 116L, 100L, 102L, 
96L, 90L, 122L, 104L, 110L, 96L, 106L, 106L, 146L, 120L, 102L, 
116L), diastolic = c(68L, 69L, 65L, 76L, 85L, 73L, 90L, 80L, 
70L, 80L, 78L, 113L, 109L, 64L, 97L, 76L, 63L, 55L, 64L, 86L, 
80L, 94L, 68L, 90L, 77L, 75L, 68L, 120L, 70L, 57L, 70L, 75L, 
78L, 90L, 70L, 67L, 75L, 70L, 68L, 82L, 80L, 71L, 70L, 62L, 71L, 
78L, 87L, 80L, 79L, 89L)), .Names = c("age", "gender", "diabetic", 
"height", "weight", "bmi", "systolic", "diastolic"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: perhaps you can try `return((rn[1] + rn[2])/2)`? not sure it will fix your problem but in your code brackets in the `return` line are misplaced

Comment: @Vincent , I had tried that way as well.. but no success..

I have edited the question for more clarity

Comment: perhaps `lm(sel~1, bmi)`? could you make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)? e.g. provide the result of `dput(bmi)`?

Comment: @Vincent, I just edited my question .. added `dput(bmi)`

Comment: Do not use `subset` inside a function; its documentation explicitly warns against using it non-interactively. Use `[` for subsetting. Also, use the `data` argument of `lm`.

Comment: @arshad: I don't think so, that's `dput(sel$bmi)`, I think we need `dput(bmi)`. And see @Roland's comment: that was my fear

Comment: @Ronald , `sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age== 10 & ibmi$gender == 1,]`
`out <- boxcox(lm(bmi~1, data= sel))`.. I made these changes in the function.. But still I facing same issue..

Comment: @Vincent, `bmi` is big file of around 6000+ records.. can I put it here?

Comment: mayeb just some of it?

Comment: @Vincent, I just added `head(bmi)` and `summary(bmi)`

Comment: it's helpless to reproduce the example. we really need `dput()`. perhaps `dput(head(bmi, 50))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113009/discussion-between-arshad-and-vincent-bonhomme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several (potential) issues:

1. `subset` should not be used inside functions. Use `[` for subsetting.
2. Scoping issue are common if you pass a fitted `lm` model to functions. Avoid that and use the `boxcox` formula method.
3. You had missing parens in your return statement. `return` is a function in R.

Thus:

```
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {
  require(MASS)
  sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age==ag & ibmi$gender == gnd,]
  out <- boxcox(bmi~1, data = sel)
  rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
  return((rn[1] + rn[2])/2)
}

lambda(6,2,bmi)
#[1] -0.4040404

sel <- subset(bmi, age==6 & gender == 2)
out <- boxcox(lm(sel$bmi~1))
rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
(rn[1] + rn[2])/2
#[1] -0.4040404
```

Comment: Side note: `return` is absolutely not needed as last statement in a function, it can be more readable with it but it adds a small overhead when the interpreter looks for the function before doing the usual return call at end of function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is when passing the `lm` class object to the `boxplot`. Just avoid using `lm` altogether and it works.

```
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {
  sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age==ag & ibmi$gender == gnd, ]
  out <- boxcox(bmi~1, data = sel)
  rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
  return ((rn[1] + rn[2])/2)
}

> lambda(6,2,bmi)
[1] -0.4040404
```

As seen, the `lm` is actually redundant. Although we can still use `lm` first, we must define the `data` both in the `lm` and `boxplot` function to make it work properly

```
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {
  sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age==ag & ibmi$gender == gnd, ]
  out <- boxcox(lm(bmi~1, data = sel), data = sel)
  rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
  return ((rn[1] + rn[2])/2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given all the comments, and with your example, here is a working function:

```
library(MASS)
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {
  sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age==ag & ibmi$gender == gnd,]
  out <- boxcox(lm(bmi~1, sel))
  rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
  return(mean(rn))
}
```

eg:

```
lambda(6,2,bmi)
```

Comment: how is it not working? is Roland answer satisfactory?

Comment: I removed the comment. the browser updated Roland's answer after I commented your answer and refreshed .. my mistake.